# Invariant to inversions 2

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, invariant-theory

> Let $a,b,c,d,e,f>0$ satisfying
>   $a+b+c+d+e+f=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{f}$
>   . Prove
>   $$ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd+ae+be+ce+de+af+bf+cf+df+ef+10\sqrt{abcdef}\geq25$$

Attempt: Prove that if $k>10$ then the inequality
$$ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd+ae+be+ce+de+af+bf+cf+df+ef+k\sqrt{abcdef}\geq15+k$$is not always true.

Also, I tried 
$$a+b+c+d+e+f\geq\frac{36}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{f}}=\frac{36}{a+b+c+f+e+f}.$$
Also, $(a+b+c+d+e+f)^2$ appears $ab+ac+ad+...+ec+ed+ef.$

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I tried averaging inequality because it is symmetrical and I made my point above

Comment: $(a+....+f) \geq 6$ Something pertinent

Comment: Show please, what exactly you made?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Harmonic arithmetic mean to find an upper bound $(a + b + c + d+f) ^ 2$

Comment: Show it. How do you work with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a+b+c+d+e+f= const$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2=const.$

Thus, by the Vasc's EV Method : https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf (corollary 1.8 (b))

it's enough to prove our inequality for equality case of five variables.

Now, let $b=c=d=e=f$ and $a=xb.$

Thus, the condition gives $$a+5b=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{5}{b}$$ and we need to p-rove that
$$5ab+10b^2+10\sqrt{ab^5}\geq25$$ or
$$x+2+2\sqrt{\frac{5x+1}{x+5}}\geq\frac{5x(x+5)}{5x+1}$$ or
$$\sqrt{\frac{5x+1}{x+5}}\geq\frac{7x-1}{5x+1}$$ and the rest is smooth.

Comment: Why did you match the variants?

Comment: Dear Michael Rozenberg, in Vasc's EV, if two quantities are fixed, the 3rd quantity is maximized or minimized at EV. However, in this problem, there are four quantities, i.e., $\sum a$ and $\sum a^2$ and $\sum \frac{1}{a}$ and $abcdef$.

Comment: @River Li Yes, you are right. It's my mistake. I'll delete this delirium. Thank you! The topic starter needs to delete his accept.

Comment: @Sullo Delete please your accept.